# I am not able to set the Title of UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my code

```
navigator=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:contacts];
//navigator.title=@"Select contact to call";
navigator.title=@"Select the number to call";

[self.navigator setDelegate:self];
[window addSubview:[navigator view]];
```

I am not able to se the title of UINavigationController please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `UINavigationController` is using the title of the controller which it is currently viewing. So instead of setting the title of your `UINavigationController`, you have to set the title of your `RootViewController` correctly:

```
contacts.title = @"Select contact to call";
```

Comment: I also want to add the button on UINavigationController how it will be?